# detect host/ip of another site which use js to make requests to my rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-services, http

I have a js-script (client-side) on site `A` which makes requests to my rails app (site `B`).

When this request occurs, how can site `B` detect host/ip of site `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the referrer information you get on the serverside.

In Ruby on Rails I believe it is either

```
request.referer
```

or

```
request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Comment: the http referer can be spoofed. the remote address / ip can't. you should rely on that to have accurate results